# Batch file : SET variable=string doesn't work

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, delayedvariableexpansion

I've this code :

```
if %Ret:~6,4% EQU %Year% (
SET test=text
ECHO %test%
) else (
ECHO NO
)
```

The code enters in the if loop but it returns always Echo is off! 
I've pay attention to the space before and after the =.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Number #342 of this type of question this year.

Percent expansion occours when a block is parsed, before any line is executed.
So the `echo %test%` is expanded before the variable is set.

Therefor exists the delayed expansion, which expands when a line is executed.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if "%Ret:~6,4%" EQU "%Year%" (
  SET test=text
  ECHO !test!
) else (
  ECHO NO
)
```

Comment: It's not the problem here. I tried your solution but it put test instead of text

Comment: Yes, Alice, it is the problem and the solution.  Maybe you didn't include the setlocal command as shown in jeb's answer.